# I accidentally deleted fly/nav. How can I get it back?

Tags: modeling

I accidentally deleted fly/nav and I need it to move the camera. How can I get it back?

I don't know how to "undo" this or how to restart blender to original preferences, so you could give me new ideas, or tell me what to do so I can do it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. You mean *View > Navigation > Fly Navigation*? You cannot delete that so I'm not sure what you mean. Please add screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to *Edit* > *Preferences* > *Navigation* and first of all look what is set there under *Fly & Walk* and maybe switch something there:

[image: fly & walk]

Or more likely you have either (since it is a bit unclear what you mean by  "deleted") changed the shortcut for *Fly* navigation or disabled the shortcut.

To find out, go to *Keymap* in the *Preferences* and enter "fly" in the search field (make sure it's set to *Name* not *Key-Binding*). This should only show *View Navigation (Walk/Fly)* as result. If the shortcut was changed, there is a *Restore* button over the keymap which you can press. If not, maybe the checkbox in front of the shortcut is disabled.

[image: shortcut]